# Does $x_n \rightarrow x$ imply $x= \sup x_n$ or $x=\inf x_n$?

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

```
Prove or give a counter-example:
```

Suppose $X_n$ converges to $x$, and let $S:=\{X_n:n \in\mathbb{N}\}$. Then $x=\sup S$ or $x= \inf S$. 
That is: whenever $X_n$ is a convergent sequence, then the limit is either $\sup S$ or $\inf S$.

I know this can be done by counter example, I just don't know where to start. I know I need to choose an alternating series that DOES converge. I cannot choose $(-1)^n/n$.

Comment: I think that $X_n = (-1)^n/n$ works just fine as a counterexample.

Comment: @deeznuts What's wrong with $\frac{(-1)^n}n$?

Comment: My profesor already proved that and so we cant turn in a proof of one he's already done.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the sequence $$1,-1,0,0\ldots,0$$ which converges to zero, but the supremum and infimum are $1$ and $-1$ respectively.

Or, to follow your attempt,
$$x_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2},$$
which converges to zero, but zero is neither the supremum nor infimum.